# Where/What is the wordpress function that outputs the menus?

Tags: wordpress

Looking at the Wordpress code I am struggling to find where the menus are been put together, (to be rendered).

For example, if I want to output 'menu-1' where is the function/class that creates the output result?

Does it use a class to do the creation? Does it follow a specific pattern?

Comment: Which wordpress file's code you are seeing?

Comment: The latest one, I use svn to pull the latest code.
But I suspect that area of the code is fairly stable by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Walker_Nav_Menu** And **wp_nav_menu** is behind the wordpress Navigation. According to your requirement you need to customize the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding the custom menu option that allows users to add and organize menus, you'll add this in your function.php

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

And then you can paste this code anywhere you want to display the custom menu

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'menu-header' ) ); ?>
```

the wp_nav_menu is the main function that displays menus on the WordPress page with a few arguments stored as an array. Sort_column instructs WordPress to follow the order in the options, and the container_class :.menu-header is the CSS class to style this menu. For displaying multiple menus, you can specify the id, slug, menu name with $id, $slug, $menu